# Re-opening Closed Object Error - Android

Tags: android, testing, sqlite

I'm running some tests on an application with an SQLite database. I call open when the default activity is created, and then the testSuite() method closes it up once it is finished testing. However, the same line keeps giving me an error telling me that the object is closed and I am attempting to re-open it. I have no idea where this closing could occur, and I'm one of those people that can't often proof-read their own code. Anyone mind pointing out to me why I get this error?

```
public class SQLTest extends Activity
{
public SQLAdapter adapter;
public int[] bb_count;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    bb_count = new int[21];
    bb_count[0]++;
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sqltest);
    adapter = new SQLAdapter(this);
    adapter.createDatabase();
    open();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    bb_count[1]++;
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_sqltest, menu);
    return true;
}

public SQLAdapter accessAdapter()
{
    bb_count[2]++;
    return adapter;
}

public void open()
{
    bb_count[3]++;
    adapter.open();
}

public void close()
{
    bb_count[4]++;
    adapter.close();
}

public long insert(String name, String field)
{
    bb_count[5]++;
    long id = adapter.insert(name, field);
    return id;
}

public long insert(int id, String name, String field)
{
    bb_count[5]++;
    id = (int) adapter.insert(id, name, field);
    return id;
}

public int delete(int id)
{
    bb_count[7]++;
    int rowsDeleted = adapter.delete(id);
    return rowsDeleted;
}

public int update(int id, String name, String field)
{
    bb_count[8]++;
    int rowsUpdated = adapter.update(id, name, field);
    return rowsUpdated;
}

public boolean get(Cursor cursor, int id)
{
    bb_count[9]++;
    try
    {
        bb_count[10]++;
        cursor = adapter.get(id);
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        String table = "";
        if (cursor.moveToFirst())
        {
            bb_count[11]++;
            table += "\n" + cursor.getString(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1) + " " + cursor.getString(2);
        }
        else
        {
            bb_count[12]++;
            table += "No hall found with ID: " + id;
            return false;
        }
        tv.setText(table);
        setContentView(tv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bb_count[13]++;
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean getAll(Cursor cursor)
{
    bb_count[14]++;
    try
    {
        bb_count[15]++;
        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        String table = "";
        try
        {
            bb_count[16]++;
            cursor = adapter.getAll();
            if (cursor.moveToFirst())
            {
                bb_count[17]++;
                do
                {
                    bb_count[18]++;
                    table += "\n" + cursor.getString(0) + " " + cursor.getString(1) + " " + cursor.getString(2);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            bb_count[19]++;
        }
        tv.setText(table);
        setContentView(tv);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        bb_count[20]++;
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

public String blockCoverage()
{
    String coverage = "";
    for (int x = 0; x < bb_count.length; x++)
        coverage += x + " " + bb_count[x] + "\n";
    return coverage;
}
}

public class SQLSuiteVer2 extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<SQLTest>
{
SQLTest activity;

public SQLSuiteVer2()
{
    super(SQLTest.class);
}

protected void setUp() throws Exception
{
    super.setUp();
    setActivityInitialTouchMode(false);
    activity = getActivity();
}

public void testPreConditions()
{
    assertTrue(activity.accessAdapter() != null);
    assertTrue(activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().checkDatabase());
}

public void testSuite() throws IOException
{
    int length = 100;
    Cursor[] cursors = new Cursor[5];
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        cursors[x] = activity.accessAdapter().getAll();

    for (int x = 0; x < length; x++)
    {
        randomTest(cursors);
    }
    System.out.println( activity.blockCoverage()
            + activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().blockCoverage());
    for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++)
        cursors[x].close();
    activity.close();
}

public void testInsert(Cursor cursor, String name, String field)
{

    int id = (int) activity.insert(name, field);
    assert (activity.get(cursor, id));
}

public void testDelete(Cursor cursor, int id)
{
    try
    {   
        activity.delete(id);
        assert (!activity.get(cursor, id));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Row doesn't exist.");
    }
}

public void testUpdate(int id, String name, String field)
{
    Cursor cursor = activity.accessAdapter().get(id);
    activity.update(id, name, field);
    Cursor cursor2 = activity.accessAdapter().get(id);
    assertTrue(!(cursor.equals(cursor2)));
}

public void testGet(Cursor cursor, int id)
{
    assert activity.get(cursor, id);
}

public void testGetAll(Cursor cursor)
{
    assert activity.getAll(cursor);
}

public void testJoin(Cursor cursor, Cursor cursor2)
{
    String table = SQLAdapter.TABLE_OS;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Blah"
        + "_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + "OrderNo. INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + "Item TEXT NOT NULL)";
    try
    {
        cursor = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not make new 'Blah' table.");
    }
    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " FULL JOIN Blah ON "
            + table + "._id=Blah._id";
    try
    {
        cursor2 = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not join 'Blah' and '" + table + "' tables.");
    }
}

public void testJoinCopy(Cursor cursor, Cursor cursor2)
{
    String table = SQLAdapter.TABLE_OS;
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " FULL JOIN " + table + "2 ON "
            + table + "._id=" + table + "2._id";

    cursor = activity.accessAdapter().getAll();
    try
    {
        cursor2 = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not join '" + table +"' and its copy.");
    }

}

public void testJoinUnrelated(Cursor cursor, Cursor cursor2)
{
    String table = SQLAdapter.TABLE_OS;
    String sql = "CREATE TABLE Blah2"
            + "Name TEXT PRIMARY KEY, "
            + "OrderNo. INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            + "Item TEXT NOT NULL)";
    try
    {
        cursor = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not make new 'Blah' table.");
    }

    sql = "SELECT * FROM " + table + " FULL JOIN Blah ON "
            + table + "._id=Blah._id";
    try
    {
        cursor2 = activity.accessAdapter().accessHelper().accessDatabase().rawQuery(sql, null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new Error("Could not join two tables without a similar '_id'.");
    }
}

public void testOverWrite(Random rand, String name, String field)
{
    int id;
    do
    {
        id = rand.nextInt();
    } while (activity.accessAdapter().get(id) == null);

    Cursor cursor = activity.accessAdapter().get(id);
    activity.insert(id, name, field);
    Cursor cursor2 = activity.accessAdapter().get(id);
    assertTrue(!(cursor.equals(cursor2)));
}

@SuppressLint("NewApi")
public void randomTest(Cursor[] cursors)
{
    String name = "", field = "";
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randOp = rand.nextInt(9);
    int randName, randField, id;

    Cursor cursor = activity.accessAdapter().getAll();
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int start = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    cursor.moveToLast();
    int end = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0));
    int range = (end - start) + 1;

    int cursorChoice = rand.nextInt(5);
    int cursor2Choice = rand.nextInt(5);

    switch (randOp)
    {
    case 0:
        randName = rand.nextInt(45);
        name = getRandomName(randName);
        int nullNotNull = rand.nextInt(2);
        switch (nullNotNull)
        {
        case 0:
            field = null;
            break;
        case 1:
            randField = rand.nextInt(24);
            field = getRandomField(randField);
            break;
        }
        testInsert(cursors[cursorChoice], name, field);
        break;
    case 1:
        id = rand.nextInt(range)+start;
        testDelete(cursors[cursorChoice], id);
        break;
    case 2:
        int selection = rand.nextInt(5);
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 0:
            randName = rand.nextInt(45);
            id = rand.nextInt(range)+start;
            name = getRandomName(randName);
            testUpdate(id, name, "");
            break;
        default:
            randName = rand.nextInt(45);
            name = getRandomName(randName);
            randField = rand.nextInt(24);
            field = getRandomField(randField);
            id = rand.nextInt(range)+start;
            testUpdate(id, name, field);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 3:
        id = rand.nextInt(range)+start;
        testGet(cursors[cursorChoice], id);
        break;
    case 4:
        testGetAll(cursors[cursorChoice]);
        break;
    case 5:
        selection = rand.nextInt(5);
        switch (selection)
        {
        case 0:
            randName = rand.nextInt(45);
            name = getRandomName(randName);
            testOverWrite(rand, name, "");
            break;
        default:
            randName = rand.nextInt(45);
            name = getRandomName(randName);
            randField = rand.nextInt(24);
            field = getRandomField(randField);
            testOverWrite(rand, name, field);
            break;
        }
        break;
    case 6:
        testJoin(cursors[cursorChoice], cursors[cursor2Choice]);
        break;
    case 7:
        testJoin(cursors[cursorChoice], cursors[cursor2Choice]);
        break;
    case 8:
        testJoin(cursors[cursorChoice], cursors[cursor2Choice]);
        break;
    }   
}

 }
```

Here's where I'm getting the errors:

```
java.lang.Error: Could not make new 'Blah' table.
at com.example.sql2.test.SQLSuiteVer2.testJoin(SQLSuiteVer2.java:99)
at com.example.sql2.test.SQLSuiteVer2.randomTest(SQLSuiteVer2.java:410)
at com.example.sql2.test.SQLSuiteVer2.testSuite(SQLSuiteVer2.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:214)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:199)
at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:192)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1584)
```

Everything works until I added the three join methods and the one overwrite one.

Comment: please post the stack - its alot of code to look through.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I meant to do that, but forgot. I've done it now.

Answer (score 0):

Your question mentioned re-opening Closed Object Error. Yet your logcat shows java.lang.Error exception. Which error is it?

If using your logcat as a guide. Perhaps this is the second time you ran the tests, which the table 'Blah' already exist? You can't create the same table twice with the same name. A way to fix this is to delete all tables from 'setUp' method. So that your tests start from empty database. Or you can make the test method 'testJoin' delete table 'Blah' if already exists, and recreate it again.

Comment: Oh, yeah, that was an error I personally threw in there. I'm not sure completely why I did that, but that (the re-opening closed object error) was the error that came before. Sorry about that.

Comment: Actually, I remember now. I thought that would prevent my tests from crashing, instead just printing out in LogCat (which, by the way, this is the trace from the JUnit view in Eclipse with ADT).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem myself. I went and tried looking deeper down (I assumed that the problem couldn't be passed what I added, considering that the code worked just fine before the additions) and found this:

```
public SQLAdapter open() throws SQLException
{
    try
    {
        helper.openDatabase();
        helper.close();
        database = helper.getWritableDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, " open >>" + e.toString());
        throw e;
    }
    return this;
}
```

I think this was the cause of the problem (the helper is a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper which I used to create/copy and access the database). I deleted the helper.close() part as I have a method that already does so in my SQLAdapter class, so the helper.close() method will get called later on when I'm done with my work.